# Rails "assert" undefined method '+'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this is a very basic question...Why isn't the `assert` method working in this simple example?

```
assert true
```

I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

This is in rails 4.2.1.

Edit: This is literally the whole block of code. All I do is enter the rails console and type assert true.

Comment: Please post the whole block of code and the full error stack trace.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with that line of code. Can we see the rest of it?

Comment: Please post more information so we can help.

Comment: This is literally the whole block of code. All I do is enter the rails console and type 'assert true'

Comment: Confirming that this can actually happen in certain situations with just that one line of code. Should not have been downvoted. Answer below by retroalgic is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there are a whole bunch of things to learn about what's the magic behind `Rake`, `Rails`,`Minitest` when you run `rake test`, but basically if you tried to gain some fundamental understand of **OOP** and **Ruby** before you get down to Rails, you won't do this in your console.

When you run **`assert true`** directly in your Rails console, it means you're calling `assert` method on an object called **`main`**. However, the **`assert`** method is defined in `assertions.rb` under **`Assertions`** module (you can inspect by running `gem open minitest` or find it where your gems are located), which is included in **`Test`** class. This means the `assert` method should be called on an instance of `Test` class, which is actually what happens when you run the tests in Rails. The `main` is just an instance of `Object` class where the method is undefined.

But the weird thing is the message you got from the console, it should be

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'assert' for main:Object`